# How to set a master pod and worker pods for remote chunking with Spring Batch in OpenShift?

Tags: kubernetes, spring-batch, openshift, partitioning, chunking

I'm trying to use Spring Batch to parse a large flatfile (order of 10s of millions of records) with remote partitioning and chunking. I've achieved this by following various tutorials with a single OpenShift pod. My question is if I am to horizontally scale to multiple pods, how do I set it so that only a single pod runs the master service/bean and the others all run only workers?

Right now my workaround has been having two deployments. One used the *master* profile with a single pod and the other uses the *worker* profile with multiple pods but this feels like an inelegant solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think that this is an inelegant solution? How would do it otherwise? I don't see any other option if you want to horizontally scale workers.

Comment: It feels inelegant because I need to have two separate builds prepared and deployed independently. I was hoping there is some sort of configuration value we can set or a sort of pod label such that the first pod to be launched is the master and all subsequent pods are workers.